# Preg_replace only last match or start from the end

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a preg_replace function that replaces the first match of NUMBERxNUMBER in a sring.
I need it to replace only the last match and i can't figure it out.

```
preg_replace("#-\d+x\d+#", "",  $string, 1)
```

I tried putting a $ before the # but doesn't work...

Thank you.

Comment: Before the *last* `#`? It should work. See https://regex101.com/r/eBqUaW/1

Comment: Or does that value appear not at the end of the string? You mean there can be some text other than `-\d+x\d+` after the last pattern occurrence?